# unable to use condition in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Follow Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "follows".* FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."follower_id" = 2 AND "follows"."follower_type" = 'User' AND "follows"."blocked" = 'f'
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1)
Conference Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "conferences".* FROM "conferences" WHERE "conferences"."id" IN (4)
=> [#<Follow id: 8, followable_id: 1, followable_type: "User", follower_id: 2, follower_type: "User", blocked: false, created_at: "2013-08-28 06:57:17", updated_at: "2013-08-28 06:57:17">, #<Follow id: 9, followable_id: 4, followable_type: "Conference", follower_id: 2, follower_type: "User", blocked: false, created_at: "2013-08-28 07:03:35", updated_at: "2013-08-28 07:03:35">]
```

This is the output I get in the console when i try

```
User.find(2).all_follows
```

I want to get the rows where the followable_type: "Conferece".

I tried this

```
 User.find(2).all_follows.find(:conditions => ["followable_type = ?", "Conference"])
```

and

```
 User.find(2).all_follows.where(:all, :conditions => ["followable_type = ?", "Conference"])
```

When I use where, it says no such function. But when i hit tab after typing where I get the following output

```
User.find(2).all_follows.where
2).all_follows.where              2).all_follows.where_sql                
2).all_follows.where_values=      2).all_follows.wheres
2).all_follows.where_clauses      2).all_follows.where_values              
2).all_follows.where_values_hash  2).all_follows.wheres=
```

Comment: It is will return all the people and conference a user is following. I am using this function as I have used the act_as_followable gem

Comment: I can see that but is it a scope (or something returning a scope) or an array?

Comment: Also show the exact error message - it's probably complaining because the parameters to `where` are incorrect

Comment: Provide the definition of your `all_follows` method. Which Rails are you using? Probably your method is not returning ActiveRelation, so you can't append scopes to it.

Comment: I think it returns an array. I tried the same using .last as well. But it still doesn't work. Still says where() method is a not a method it knows.

Comment: @jurglic I am using rails 3.2.9. Please see the link https://github.com/xpepermint/acts_as_followable for all_follows defenition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 User.find(2).all_follows.select{ |user| user.followable_type == "Conference" }
```

Comment: This is the error i get NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x000000060d8af8>

Comment: @Aravind Edited my answer.. Try this